# VS Code crashed in macOS Monterey

Tags: macos, visual-studio, apple-m1

When I tried to open VS Code today, I got this error message:

> The window has crashed (reason: 'killed', code: '9')

So I tried to reinstall it. (i deleted everything about VS Code on my mac, including some hidden files.) And it didn't work.

I right clicked on the VS Code Application icon and then clicked on show package content. And then I open the file in this path: /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron

The terminal wondow pops up and starts running, and gave a lot more error messages:

> Last login: Sun Jun 12 16:26:19 on ttys000 /Applications/Visual
> Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron ; exit; (base)
> wangtianzhu@zaihongtakaixindezhutianwang ~ % /Applications/Visual
> Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron ; exit;
> [0612/165140.220603:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir
> /Users/wangtianzhu/Library/Application
> Support/Code/Crashpad/attachments/2831a7e2-bb1e-4348-a7a7-cc2e71331216:
> No such file or directory (2) [main 2022-06-12T08:51:40.564Z]
> update#setState idle
> [0612/165140.844508:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165141.071712:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165141.085032:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165141.286074:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165143.762529:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir
> /Users/wangtianzhu/Library/Application
> Support/Code/Crashpad/attachments/5241240d-8edc-4fdf-a9a0-c909d468ddb5:
> No such file or directory (2)
> [15657:0612/165145.693860:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [15657:0612/165145.703122:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165146.093314:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165146.271355:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH [main 2022-06-12T08:51:46.284Z]
> CodeWindow: renderer process crashed (reason: killed, code: 9)
> [0612/165146.469944:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165146.645581:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165146.655591:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [15657:0612/165146.657133:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165146.832587:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165146.845818:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [0612/165146.950620:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir
> /Users/wangtianzhu/Library/Application
> Support/Code/Crashpad/attachments/d20432c4-ad90-4b2e-83ef-8d4df0326e7c:
> No such file or directory (2)
> [0612/165147.032880:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165147.206695:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165147.219042:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165147.589950:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165147.777690:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165147.789190:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [15657:0612/165147.791484:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [0612/165147.966942:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165147.981925:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165148.409551:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165148.586647:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165148.596958:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [15657:0612/165148.598065:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165148.774772:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165148.788053:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [0612/165148.974920:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165149.150306:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165149.162105:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165149.541186:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165149.721930:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165149.732888:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [15657:0612/165149.734770:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [0612/165149.915136:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165149.929546:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165150.336140:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165150.515477:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165150.526674:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [15657:0612/165150.528934:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [0612/165150.704156:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165150.716235:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165151.089639:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165151.267718:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165151.279101:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [15657:0612/165151.281101:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [0612/165151.457100:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165151.468355:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165151.835932:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165152.014206:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165152.024996:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [15657:0612/165152.026820:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [0612/165152.202656:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [15657:0612/165152.215013:ERROR:network_service_instance_impl.cc(975)]
> Network service crashed, restarting service.
> [0612/165152.591157:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [0612/165152.776788:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165152.787954:WARNING:exception_types.cc(171)] EXC_CRASH should
> not contain exception 12
> [15657:0612/165152.789838:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(983)] GPU process
> exited unexpectedly: exit_code=9
> [15657:0612/165152.789862:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(448)]
> GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
> [0612/165152.963405:WARNING:exception_snapshot_mac.cc(70)] exception
> EXC_GUARD invalid in EXC_CRASH
> [0612/165153.164918:WARNING:crash_report_exception_handler.cc(235)]
> UniversalExceptionRaise: (os/kern) failure (5) zsh: trace trap
> /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron
>
> Saving session... ...copying shared history... ...saving
> history...truncating history files... ...completed.

So does anyone has any idea how am I supposed to fix this?

Comment: possibly related issue tickets: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com%2Fmicrosoft%2Fvscode%2Fissues+%22ERROR%3Adirectory_reader_posix.cc%2842%29%22+%22opendir%22+%22No+such+file+or+directory+%282%29%22. you might want to raise an issue ticket following https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Native-Crash-Issues

Answer (score 0):

if u are disabling your SIP that's may be the reason ....
SIP status u can see it throw csrutil status