# Can't launch Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, installation, terminal, launch

I'm trying to install Visual Studio Code on my MacBook Pro, but when I launch it, the screen stays black.
I found something ...

```
Last login: Wed May 17 22:59:11 on console
alice@MacBook-Pro-2 ~ % /Applications/Visual\ Studio\ Code.app/Contents/MacOS/Electron ; exit;
[0517/230053.776458:ERROR:crash_report_database_mac.mm(792)] open lock /Users/alice/Library/Application Support/Code/Crashpad/pending/a2c622ea-85f9-4178-a522-01561903620e.dmp: Resource temporarily unavailable (35)
[2511:0517/230054.093571:ERROR:validation_errors.cc(117)] Invalid message: VALIDATION_ERROR_DESERIALIZATION_FAILED
[0517/230054.099952:WARNING:process_memory_mac.cc(93)] mach_vm_read(0x7ffee8b07000, 0x2000): (os/kern) invalid address (1)
[2511:0517/230054.374197:ERROR:interface_endpoint_client.cc(694)] Message 1456507949 rejected by interface network.mojom.NetworkService
[0517/230054.416953:ERROR:directory_reader_posix.cc(42)] opendir /Users/alice/Library/Application Support/Code/Crashpad/attachments/0c4d0b1c-b58a-4657-8cda-4e6a4d9d141f: No such file or directory (2)
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Opération terminée]
```

Any idea on what to do to be able to access VS Code ?

I tried multiple install, updating my computer, but I don't understand this error message that I got when I went into the package files (electron).

Comment: related: [VS Code crashed in macOS Monterey](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72590809/11107541). possibly related issue tickets: https://www.google.com/search?q=site%3Agithub.com%2Fmicrosoft%2Fvscode%2Fissues+%22ERROR%3Adirectory_reader_posix.cc%2842%29%22+%22opendir%22+%22No+such+file+or+directory+%282%29%22. you might want to raise an issue ticket following https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/wiki/Native-Crash-Issues.